# how to select a parent's parent when setting 100% width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a pretty simple navigation bar from scratch but I'm
having a lot of trouble setting certain widths and I want
`.navbarDropBtn` to be as wide as `.navbarMain` but it's only as wide as
the text, I've tried switching the order they appear in html but I
need `.navbarText` on top because I'm adding a smooth opacity transition
so I can transition gradients.

my question is just how can I set width to be `100%` of a parent's
parent. I don't want to use anything but `%` or `em` because `px` will cause
issues going to different screen sizes. and using specific `120%` will
cause the same problem.

```
    .navbarBody {
        width:100%;
        height: 46px;
        position: sticky;
    }
    .navbarButton, .navbarBody {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, #2a2a2a, #4a4a4a);
        z-index: 100;
    }
    .navbarButton, .navbarMain {
        float:right;
        text-align:center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        color: #fff;
        position:relative;
    }
    .navbarButton:hover, .navbarMain:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
        color:black;
        transition: .25s;
    }
    .navbarText {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbarButton:hover .navbarText {
        color:black;
        }
    .navbarMain {
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, #296a29, #4aca4a);
    }
    .navbarDropBtn {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
background-color: white; /*example only */
    }
/*hover effect*/
.navbarButton::before, .navbarMain::before {
    content: "";
    opacity:0;
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #999, #fff);
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.navbarMain::before {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg, #3a8a3a, #aafaaa);
}
.navbarButton:hover::before, .navbarMain:hover::before {
    opacity:1;
    transition:opacity .25s, content .05s;
}





 <div class="navbarBody">
                <div class="navbarMain" onclick="dropBtn()">
                    <div class="navbarText">
                        <div class="navbarDropBtn">
                far right special boi
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navbarButton">
                    <div class="navbarText">
                test 1
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="navbarButton">
                    <div class="navbarText">
                test 1 1
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's because you have added padding to navbarMain.
if you remove the paddings you'll see navbarDropBtn is as wide as navbarMain
maybe you should give paddings to it like this:

```
 .navbarMain {
     padding: 14px 0;
 }
```

this way it will have no paddings on right and left therefore will be as wide as navbarDropBtn